# Assign different value to each node in Netlogo

Tags: graph, nodes, netlogo

I'm new to this language and I'm suppose to create a graph, so far I've done very basic structure (nodes). I'd like to assign a different value to each node, this value should be taken from a list (like [1 2 3 4]) and this list should be made automaticly.

I've read this command somewhere else `[n-values <number> [self]]` But i don't really understand what `[self]` stands for.  What I'd like my program to do is to create n nodes (n is taken from the slider value) and then for each node assign values (1 2 3 4 5...n) respectively.

My code so far:

```
breed [nodes node] ;;Hacemos 'especies'(Clases) de tortugas, el objeto nodes será de una especie node. 
nodes-own [info]
to setup
  ca ;clear all shortage
  ask patches [set pcolor white] ;;hacemos todas las parcelas blancas
  create-nodes num-nodes [ ;creamos tantos nodos como el slider diga
    set shape "circle" ;con forma de circulo
    setxy random-pxcor random-pycor ;;en cualquier lugar.
  ]
  ask nodes [set info 9] ;;<<<ALL nodes have value 9 I'd like to change this!!!
  reset-ticks
end
to layout
  layout-spring nodes links .5 .5 .5
end
```

Thanks in advice!

Also: is there a better way to make a graph? (I'm going to work with flow networks!)

Comment: What's wrong with your code so far? What about it do you want to improve or change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you need `n-value <number> self`

what N-value does is to repeat the reporter in brackets n times , for example if you :

```
ask nodes [print n-values info [self]]
```

each node will print its own name for example (node 1) info times.

best place to start is  NetLogo Models Library examples there are plenty examples which use nodes and links for graphs such as Small Worlds, Team Assembly, virus network and ...

http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/

or just from netlogo choose file / Models library

This is your code with a few changes, by adding a list to choose the value of info from, however , if you think info should be assigned to the link not to the node you can add it to link-own

```
breed [nodes node] ;;Hacemos 'especies'(Clases) de tortugas, el objeto nodes será de una especie node. 
nodes-own [info]
globals
[My-Num-List]

links-own [msg]
to setup
  ca ;clear all shortage
  ask patches [set pcolor white] ;;hacemos todas las parcelas blancas
  set My-Num-List [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10] ; or any other list you need

  create-nodes num-of-nodes [ ;creamos tantos nodos como el slider diga
    set shape "circle" ;con forma de circulo
    setxy random-pxcor random-pycor ;;en cualquier lugar
    set label-color black
    set info one-of My-Num-List
    set label info
  ]

   ;;<<<ALL nodes have value 9 I'd like to change this!!!
  reset-ticks
end
to layout
  crtlinks
  layout-spring nodes links .5 .5 .5
end




to crtlinks
  ask turtles  
  [
    create-links-with n-of 2 other turtles 
    [
      set msg one-of [ "C" "A" "B"]
      set label msg
      set label-color black
      set thickness 0.2
    ]
  ]
```